# Can Sanji use COA(Color of Arms/Busoshoku)?

Tags: one-piece

He didn't use it on Punk Hazard and he wasn't on Dressrosa. However it was mentioned in the manga when he battled his father in the current whole cake island arc that his haki is strong but it was not specified which haki.

Can Sanji use armament?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Sanji can use CoA, even if it was not shown yet to my knowledge. We know this from Chapter 668, when Law asks Luffy who of his crew is able to fight Caesar, a Logia user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I didn't start reading the manga until after the dressrosa arc ended. So when I started reading they just had the party and were on the way to Zou. How did Luffy know that they could use Haki? We didn't see Zoro's until he fought Pica.

Comment: @KazRodgers We don't know for sure. Either they discussed it after the reunion in Shabaody islands, or - which is my own opinion, one who has mastered Haki is able to sense others, which I think will be especially true for someone like Luffy who can use Haoshoku Haki.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he can use it. It was even stated when he was fighting his father in chapter 833: he was blocking his spear attacks and Judge said that he did not expect him to have Haki.

[image]